# How to output a string to the browser by writing that string in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am a begginer to Ruby On Rails.So I was thinking instead of making any view file can't we display any string in the browser by writing " **puts "anything"** " in the controller's file??If yes then I have tried once by writing this code

```
class OnecController < ApplicationController
  def one
    print "hello";
  end
end
```

But I am nt able to get the output! Any help ???

Comment: In rails, stdout is not directed to the view/browser, like it is with cgi in, say, python or perl  The fact that you wrote `print` instead of `puts`, and the fact that you ended the line with a semi-colon means that it would be very helpful if you read a basic ruby tutorial.  How about 'Ruby in 20 Minutes': http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/.

Answer (score 5):

yes, do:

```
render text: 'your text'
```

Comment: i thought the question is stupid , with your answer even the stupid question make sense.

Comment: :) there are no stupid questions: they always denote a willingness to learn!

Comment: Actually I have started this today.Sorry If I am wasting the time but
Do I have to create any method like "def somethin"?and write that render :text into dat?

Comment: well, yes of course there's lot more to add...
you should create your method, and add the render text in your method. Then in your config/routes.rb add a least one route that routes to this action, something like:

get "blabla" => "yourcontroller#youraction"

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the controller's action in the view file using your routes file. You need to set the route

```
  root :to => "onecContrller#one"
```

and as mentioned you just need to render text that is

```
 class OnecController < ApplicationController
  def one
    render text: 'text to print'
  end
end
```

and I would recommend if you have just started with rails go through these [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In modern rails (version 7 answer), use `plain`:

```
class OnecController < ApplicationController
  def one
    render plain: 'text to print'
  end
end
```